# How to Loop on a file.txt containing a list of names?

Tags: bash, list, loops, command-line

I am using **MacOS**.

I am trying to annotate Transcription factors Motifs through the **fimo** tool.
I need to run fimo on multiple Motifs **--motif $line** names contained in the file **MotifsList.txt**.
In order to work, fimo need to access at 2 other files (**file.meme**, **file.fa**) beside the MotifsList.txt one.
I would run everything from the **command line** using a produced **file.sh** containing the script.
All the files needed; .txt, .sh, .meme and .fa are stored in the same folder called Motifs_analysis.
I would like the out-put **Resultfile** to be saved in the same cd.

1. Rows in the **MotifsList.txt** file :

```
MOTIF BU0001.Arid3a_primary
MOTIF MA0151.1 Arid3a
MOTIF MA0601.1 Arid3b
MOTIF ARNT_HUMAN.H11MO.0.B
....
```

2. **file.sh** file containing the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    fimo --thresh 1e-4 --no-qvalue --max-stored-scores 10000000 --motif $line --text file.meme genome.fa > ResultFile
done < $1
```

3. **Command line** input to start the bash job :

```
cd /Users/myho2345/Desktop/Motifs_analysis
chmod +x file.sh
./file.sh MotifsList.txt
```

*Error:

`zsh: ./file.sh: bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M: no such file or directory`

*The scripts are not correct. Where am I doing wrong?*

*Best and thank you so much for the help!!!!*

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. "_using bash, the file.sh cannot be find_": did you check its existence (`ls /Users/myho2345/Desktop/Motifs_analysis/file.sh`)?

Comment: @Myke - _the file.sh cannot be find_ cannot be the true error message, can it?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes it is in the folder and each letter of the name is the same in the script.

Comment: @Myke So, please, instead of rephrasing, copy-paste exactly the error message. every detail matters.

Comment: @Armali zsh: ./file.sh: bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M: no such file or directory

Comment: @Myke Much better: it is not your script that's missing, it is either `/bin/bash` (unlikely under macOS) or the format of your script that's wrong. Does it come from Windows?

Comment: Try using`dos2unix` to remove the windows line endings in the script.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I am trying to run it on MacOS yes.

Comment: @justaguy do you mean on the I should produce the script in .txt file, use the dos2unix tool and then set it as .sh right?

Comment: @Myke Your `file.sh` script is formatted for Windows. Its newline characters are not that of BSD (macOS). This is why you see a strange `^M` in the error message. This says that the line `#!/bin/bash` does not end with the BSD newline byte. Instead it probably ends with the two bytes Windows uses for this purpose. You need to convert these newlines from Windows to BSD. As suggested by justaguy you can try `dos2unix`.

Comment: glad to help :).

Comment: @justaguy Thank you for the help! I thanked you as well but didn't worked apparently. Can't see my posted message.

Comment: @Myke just to be clear, there's no need to rename the script before/after running `dos2unix`; you can run `dos2unix file.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^M` is a carriage-return characters in DOS filesystems, it is "invisible".

2 options to fix:

```
# Option 1
dos2unix file.sh

# Option 2
sed -i 's/\r//g' file.sh
```